# MySQL Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to create the 'Project table I get this error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table 'Employee'.

My syntax:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test;
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer (
CustomerID VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
CustomerName VARCHAR(50),
CustAdress VARCHAR(70),
CustEmail VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (
EmpID VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
EmpName VARCHAR(50),
Position VARCHAR(30),
EmpTimePrice INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (EmpID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Project (
ProjectNo VARCHAR(7),
ProjectName VARCHAR(50),
StartDate DATE,
ProjTimePrice INT(6),
CustomerID VARCHAR(7),
EmpID VARCHAR(7),
PRIMARY KEY (ProjectNo),
FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) REFERENCES Employee (EmpID),
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID) 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProjectWork (
ProjectNo VARCHAR(7),
EmpID VARCHAR(7),
PWDATE DATE,
HoursWorked INT(5),
FOREIGN KEY (ProjectNo) REFERENCES Project (ProjectNo),
FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) REFERENCES Employee (EmpID)
);
```

The names look correct to me and I have referenced the foreign key so I don't understand why I get this error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Nothing wrong](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xDeX3h9eSx4o48xVk1Rjr/0) to me.

Comment: look this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/ , maybe you missed the ON UPDATE / ON DELETE actions

Comment: @shushu304 if you read carefully the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), you can see the `ON UPDATE/CASCADE` are between brackets -> optional

Comment: If your tables were previously created, their structure may be differents. If this is for **testing** or **developpement**, and **not in production** and the potentials datas **can be lost**, add before the lines `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` this instruction : `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableName;` which will **delete** the table and its content

Comment: i wonder why you use VARCHAR datatype in some tables for numbers

Comment: @Cid Yea It's just for testing purposes so I've tried to drop the whole database and recreate the tables but the same error occurs so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Don't know really, could probably have used INT or NUMERIC for the primarykeys but just used VARCHAR

Comment: `VARCHAR` shouldn't be a problem for an index, but it's preferred to use an `INT`, the size in octet being lower

Comment: i run your code, it's working for me without any errors

Answer (score 34):

This normally happens when the two tables have different Table engines. so check both tables if they have same table engines. for example  MYISAM  do not support Foreign Keys

Comment: help me!!!!   I have change toENGINE=INNODB, and now work my query

Comment: This absolutely helped

Comment: wow I was on a flight to hawaii and spent 8 hours trying to figure this out without the internet.

Comment: You saved my life. Had to go through more than 50 stack overflow questions to find this. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer!  You help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just edited EmpID to empID and it worked for some reason.

Comment: I am way late to this thread, but I would say the case shouldn't matter as SQL is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to get this error is referencing a table that doesn't exist yet. Eg if you run the following code on a new schema:

```sql
create table ttest (bob varchar(10) not null, 
    constraint fkbob foreign key (bob) references other(bob) );
```

... you will get the MySQL error:

```
Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table 'other'
```

Because the `other` table doesn't exist.

The code in the question above creates `Employee` before referencing it. However, note that the `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements have `IF EXISTS`, but there are no `DROP IF EXISTS` statements, as when creating a new database. If you were debugging a table creation script, changing and fixing things as you go, it would have been pretty easy to get into an inconsistent state where the tables were out of synch with the code. This would also explain why other people could run the code cleanly, because these tables didn't exist in their schema yet.